# HibernateTemplate findByExample returns no results

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, query-by-example

I'm trying to use Hibernate QBE (actually, Spring's HibernateTemplate.findByExample() ) to return a list of users by their username. I use a "known good" value to search on (the username "JOHN.SMITH" does exist in the database).

Unfortunately, I get no results back. Below is the unit test.

```
@Test
public void testQueryByExample() {

    User qbeUser = new User();
    qbeUser.setUsername("JOHN.SMITH");

    List<User> userList = userDao.queryByExample(qbeUser);
    Assert.notNull(userList);
    Assert.isTrue(userList.size() > 0, "List of returned users must not be 0");

}
```

The queryByExample() method is defined in a generic DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> queryByExample(T obj) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByExample(obj);
}
```

Is there any sort of special configuration needed for QBE to work?

Comment: I second @skaffman's request, turning Hibernate SQL logging would definitely help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was pure stupidity on my part.

The classes being used as examples had some ints and booleans (primitives) in them. Since those values default to 0 and false, the queries were failing.

Comment: Yes, `findByExample()` includes all primitive attributes in its criteria, but ignores all non-primitive attributes whose value is null.  The Hibernate `Example` class, however, has more flexible criteria options.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples.

Comment: Amazing comment. I spent a long time looking for the right docs and couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass spring configuration file otherwise how would it will get connection and pooling information.. use @ annotation to load spring file above class declaration.

Comment: The Test class is annotated with 

   @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")

The class under test is being successfully injected. My other methods that don't use QBE are fine, but QBE doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude zero values by calling the excludeZeroes() method which is defined in the Example class in Hibernate. Adding hibernate.show_sql property to your hibernate.cfg.xml file will help you to see which values are set to 0 in the SQL query that Hibernate creates.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html#excludeZeroes--

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your hibernate.cfg.xml file:
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

Run your application. It will display the SQL query that Hibernate generates.
By looking at the where clause, you will see what fields are used for filtering.
[Netbeans screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMLZX.png)

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parking.class);//deprecated since 5.2
Parking p = new Parking();
p.setCity("BROOKLYN");
Example ex = Example.create(p);
ex.excludeZeroes();   //exclude zero-valued properties
c.add(ex);
```

Hibernate Example object will exclude zero-valued properties with the excludeZeroes() method.

You may exclude certain properties by name with excludeProperty() method, or you may exclude nothing with the excludeNone() method.